# insert one more row in a table if the day is saturday

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with a monthly report of some groups. I want to add one more row in the table if the day is saturday.

```
<tr>
    <td>".$data."</td>
    <td>"."<i>".$totMirela."</i> <b style='color:green'>".$grupi['Mirela']['kontratat_ok']."</b> <br><b style='color:red;'>".$grupi['Mirela']['kontratat_ko']."</b> <b style='color:blue;'>".$grupi['Mirela']['kontratat_att']."</b> <br><b style='color:brown'>".$kontratat_ore[$data]['Mirela']."</b> <u><i>".number_format($rezeMirela, 2)."</i><u></td>
    <td>"."<i>".$totANISA."</i> <b style='color:green'>".$grupi['Anisa']['kontratat_ok']."</b> <br><b style='color:red;'>".$grupi['Anisa']['kontratat_ko']."</b> <b style='color:blue;'>".$grupi['Anisa']['kontratat_att']."</b> <br><b style='color:brown'>".$kontratat_ore[$data]['Anisa']."</b> <u><i>".number_format($rezeANISA, 2)."</i><u></td>
    <td>"."<i>".$totARMAND."</i> <b style='color:green'>".$grupi['Armand']['kontratat_ok']."</b> <br><b style='color:red;'>".$grupi['Armand']['kontratat_ko']."</b> <b style='color:blue;'>".$grupi['Armand']['kontratat_att']."</b> <br><b style='color:brown'>".$kontratat_ore[$data]['Armand']."</b> <u><i>".number_format($rezeARMAND, 2)."</i><u></td>
    <td>"."<i>".$totBLERTA."</i> <b style='color:green'>".$grupi['Blerta']['kontratat_ok']."</b> <br><b style='color:red;'>".$grupi['Blerta']['kontratat_ko']."</b> <b style='color:blue;'>".$grupi['Blerta']['kontratat_att']."</b> <br><b style='color:brown'>".$kontratat_ore[$data]['Blerta']."</b> <u><i>".number_format($rezeBLERTA, 2)."</i><u></td>
    <td>"."<i>".$totDORIS."</i> <b style='color:green'>".$grupi['Doris']['kontratat_ok']."</b> <br><b style='color:red;'>".$grupi['Doris']['kontratat_ko']."</b> <b style='color:blue;'>".$grupi['Doris']['kontratat_att']."</b> <br><b style='color:brown'>".$kontratat_ore[$data]['Doris']."</b> <u><i>".number_format($rezeDORIS, 2)."</i><u></td>
    <td>"."<i>".$totORNELA."</i> <b style='color:green'>".$grupi['Ornela']['kontratat_ok']."</b> <br><b style='color:red;'>".$grupi['Ornela']['kontratat_ko']."</b> <b style='color:blue;'>".$grupi['Ornela']['kontratat_att']."</b> <br><b style='color:brown'>".$kontratat_ore[$data]['Ornela']."</b> <u><i>".number_format($rezeORNELA, 2)."</i><u></td>
    <td>"."<i>".$totXHULJANO."</i> <b style='color:green'>".$grupi['Xhuljano']['kontratat_ok']."</b> <br><b style='color:red;'>".$grupi['Xhuljano']['kontratat_ko']."</b> <b style='color:blue;'>".$grupi['Xhuljano']['kontratat_att']."</b> <br><b style='color:brown'>".$kontratat_ore[$data]['Xhuljano']."</b> <u><i>".number_format($rezeXHULJANO, 2)."</i><u></td>
    <td>"."<i>".$kontratat_tot[$data]['totali']."</i> <b style='color:green'>".$kontratat_tot[$data]['ok']."</b> <br><b style='color:red;'>".$kontratat_tot[$data]['ko']."</b> <b style='color:blue;'>".$kontratat_tot[$data]['att']."</b> <br><b style='color:brown'>".$giorno_ore."</b> <u><i>".number_format($reze_giorno, 2)."</i><u></td>
</tr>";
```

The $data variable has the date wich is in this format ("Y-m-d") or simply 2016-03-09 . Now if the day is saturday i wand to add one more row in this table.[image] Thank you all!

Comment: And what is stopping you from doing this? Take a look at [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) manual how to check if the day is saturday..

Comment: `if($row['col'] == 'saturday')` in a `while` loop. Careful though, `saturday` and `Saturday` are two different animals.

Comment: @Fred-ii- : hehe animals?? You make me laugh. ;-)

Comment: @RaviHirani *Yep!* One may bite or roar, while another may not ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Agree with you ;-)

Comment: @RaviHirani I think that PHP's day check is camel case `Saturday`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php with lowercase `L` => `l` option if they're looking for the full word. If not, then `D` for *"A textual representation of a day, three letters"*. Edit: Ah, you edited

Comment: @Fred-ii-  Yes you are correct as always. I always learn something new from your answers and comments. Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First You need to check the day.

Example:

3 Chars Name of Day
With 'D' parameter You will get a 3 chars string for the day.

```
$timestamp = strtotime('2016-03-10');

$day = date('D', $timestamp);
var_dump($day);

//Output
string 'Thu'
```

Full Name of Day
With 'l' parameter You will get a full name of day string

```
$timestamp = strtotime('2016-03-10');

$day = date('l', $timestamp);
var_dump($day);

//Output
string 'Thursday'
```

Then You need to insert this in your code in a `while` loop or an `if` to check the columns.

This is the function to check the day:

```
function DayCheck($inputDate){
   $timestamp = strtotime($inputDate);
   $day = date('l', $timestamp);
   return $day;
}
```

And this is how to use in your code:

```
if(DayCheck($row['col']) == 'Saturday'){
   //... some code ...
   //... add new row ...
   //... other code ...
}
```